# Get touch points in UIScrollView through UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, touch

i am using UIScrollview and UITapGestureRecognizer for getting touch event.

Now, i want x and y coordinates for my touch position.

any help Please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your gesture recognizer handler:

```
 CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
```

you could specify a different view, if you need it.

or u can use this also
It belongs in a View rather than ViewController, and would look something like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)evt {
  UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
  CGPoint pt=[touch locationInView:self];
  // ...make your button at 'pt'...
}
```

Comment: its working but if i scroll ,and zoom scrollview then position is not right

Comment: u have declare touchesEnd event in which u program for that or search on google.