# Delphi iOS touch points

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am wanting to get the touch points in an iOS app under Delphi (preferably as an event).
Is there an interface for this that is exposed?

I found this:
[Get touch points in UIScrollView through UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936314/get-touch-points-in-uiscrollview-through-uitapgesturerecognizer).
But I would not know if its possible to convert this code.

I am trying to implement a number of on-screen sliders (audio faders) so that the user and slide their finger to move it up and down. I plan to put a transparent rectangle control over top of the sliders so that I can get multiple touch points and move more than one simultaneously.

Comment: The question/answer you link to is presumably Cocoa. Can you do a direct translation of a Cocoa excerpt to FMX? I'd be surprised if you could. I'd expect FMX to abstract that away. Perhaps what you really need is some Cocoa controls: http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsicl.asp

Answer (score 0):

After going down this rabbit hole about as far as possible I am sad to say that's its not possible to get multiple touch points in Delphi. This is very shortsighted and appears to be a trivial oversight by Embarcadero.

Essentially the Delphi UIView implementation does not expose the "multipleTouchEnabled" property so the touch events inside of FMX.Platform.iOS.pas will never receive more than one touch event.

I am posting this to save the next person the time that I put into find this disappointing answer.